# Scroll outside website's window area?

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, bounds

Is it possible to scroll outside the window area so that you can have negative top,left scroll values?
scrolling negative in a div would also be fine.
I've tried searching for this, but all I find are related to scrollbars that don't show up or related to content that expands past the right/bottom edges of windows/divs. What I'm interested in, is being able to scroll left, and up past the 0,0 x,y origin.